# java how to write a method accept map with different key types?

Tags: java, generics

I have maps with different key types and same value type, I want one generic method to process all the different key maps, like

```
Map<Integer,String> intKeyMap;
Map<String,String> strKeyMap;

public void processMap(Map m) {
//iterate the map and do something 
}
```

I have limited knowledge of generics, how to make the "processMap" method to accept different key maps and process them?

-----------edit with below details after reading the replies---------

? wildcard is the answer actually solved my initial question:). will get this one closed. thanks for the help.

Comment: The thing is, `Integer` and `String` don't really have much in common with each other, except for both being subclasses of `Object`.  So, generics might not leave you in a situation where you could do much with such a generic key map.

Comment: One option would be to wrap the key (integer or string) in your own class. Otherwise, I think this really just calls into question your design choices. Why do you need two maps, one with integers and one with strings as keys, when they contain similar information? Can you convert one into the other?

Comment: What is *"something"* inside `processMap`, what do you want to do?

Comment: Second @TimBiegeleisen. I can't think of any use case where you would want to process the two different maps in a similar way. If the `Map<String, String>` map key actually holds Integers, you should convert (or attempt to) to Integer Before putting into a `Map<Integer, String>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
public void processMap(Map<?, ?> m)
{

}
```

allows you to do that:

> In generic code, the question mark (?), called the wildcard,
>   represents an unknown type

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Since the value is always a `String`, you might modify it into `public void processMap(Map<?, String> m)`

Answer (score 3):

You could even try:

```
public <T> void processMap(Map<T, String> m)
{
  Iterator<T> it;
  it = m.keySet().iterator();
  ...
}
```